# How do i pass java script variable into java code snippet in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to redirect the user into last accessed page after session expire and i prompt user to login again. In that i passed last page url into one parameter and invoke a seesioerror action for validate the user.

I have this code snippet :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentURL = window.location.href;

    </script>
     <%

        String url= "<script>document.writeln(currentURL);</script>";

        Object obj = session.getAttribute("user");
        if (obj == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/SessionError?backurl=" + url);
        }

     %>
```

Now my problem is whenever I print the Java String varaible  url using  `<%   out.print("URL" + url);%>` it correctly print the page URL.

But If pass it on this line `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/SessionError?backurl=" + url);` inside the snippet. It only pass `<script>document.writeln(currentURL);</script>` not the current page url like **http://www.mysite.com/home**. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989888/get-request-url-from-jsp)

And please don't mix sciplets and Javascript code. Its a mess.

Answer (score 1):

JSP is server side language, it will be executed before http response gets back to client. By saying that, you can use JSP variables in javascript but not the other way around. 
You can use javascript : **document.referrer** to get previous url