# How to make an image show up when on a certain page jsp

Tags: jsp, url

I have jsp shopping pages that need to have specific images assigned when specific category is clicked. So I want to say "if url ends in 'category/bags' then choose this code.

I see "category/bags" in my browser on the page, but when I print out the servlet path it calls the page "CategoryDisplay.jsp" in browser.

I understand there's a difference in the views and I need to use RequestDispatcher.forward.

So how do I A) print out the page that I am on to see what it ends with in request dispatcher forward so I can then B) properly assign that category page in a test statement.

I've tried this: A)

```
    <% System.out.println("request URI= " + request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"));
```

B)

```
     <c:if test="${fn:endsWith(javax.servlet.forward.request_uri, 'Bags')}">
    <div class="hero" style="background-image: url('/images/static/shop/hero_bags.jpg');">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>Bags</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: You want to [get the request Url from jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989888/get-request-url-from-jsp). It's all there on Stackoverflow...

Comment: <c:if test="${fn:endsWith(javax.servlet.forward.request_uri, 'Bags')}"> This doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you do not access the request Url in the proper way. Take a look at the proposed answer and it'll work out fine.

Comment: I have looked at it for days. I don't know jsp. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, that's why I'm on here.

Comment: Use this as test condition `${fn:endsWith(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri'], 'bags')`