# How to get the previous page URL from request in servlet after dispatcher.forward(request, response)

Tags: servlets, request

I'm using the servlet which redirects me with the help of

```
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

in the end. But after this I want to get the page(path) from which I was redirected to use it in next servlet command(to go to previous page). How could I get it?
Or previous URL is not contained in request parameters and I should add it myself?
Will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

See
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/constant-values.html
and
[How to get the url of the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089528/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-client)

Comment: Please fix references. The link is currently down.

Answer (score 21):

`String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
response.sendRedirect(referer);`

SEE: 
[*Link to forum answer*](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-27270.html)

Answer (score 1):

Any method will return source URL when you do forward(..) so my solution is to define a filter to store the requestURL() in a request attribute to check later. To do this in your web.xml write:

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.CustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

Then in `CustomFilter` class:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse rsp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.setAttribute("OriginURL", req.getRequestURL().toString());
        chain.doFilter(req, rsp);
    }
}
```

Then you can get it everywhere in your code with ServletRequest object with:

```
request.getAttribute("OriginURL").toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can store that `url` in `HttpSession` and retrieve it in next servlet when you need.

Comment: as much i know thats the should be a nice way.